# plotting the SIR model for infectious diseases in python with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot an SIR model in Python with matplotlib that has a:

a) population of 2200

b) and shows the course of the population being effected over the course of 30 days

c) with (Delta)t = 0.01 
-Delta being change and t being time

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

def SIR(population, days, dt):
    susceptible = population - 1
    infected = 1.0
    recovered = 0.0
    recRate = 0.25
    infRate = 0.0004
    SList = [susceptible]
    IList = [infected]
    RList = [recovered]
    timeList =[0]
    for day in range(1, int(days/dt) + 1):
        population = population + (0.0004 * population - 0.25) * dt
        t = day * dt
        timeList.append(t)
        SList.append(SList)
        IList.append(SList)
        RList.append(SList)

    pyplot.plot(timeList, SList, label = 'Susceptible')
    pyplot.plot(timeList, IList, label = 'Infected')
    pyplot.plot(timeList, RList, label = 'Recovered')
    pyplot.legend(loc = 'center right')
    pyplot.xlabel('Days')
    pyplot.ylabel('Individuals')
    pyplot.show()

SIR(2200, 30, 0.01)
```

So when I run my code now, matplotlib appears, but none of my data is showing. What am I doing wrong when trying to loop using the difference equations?

Then end result is suppose to produce three lines on the graph, "Susceptible", "Infected", and "Recovered", each showing the rate at which the population is effected by the disease.

Comment: It might be that code not listed above is using the variable `recoverd` when it should be spelled `recovered`

Comment: I actually caught that right before you posted, I still am not entirely sure how to for loop coupled difference equations, I think that is the issue at hand. It makes since on paper sort of, but translating it into python is proving to be tricky.

Comment: Is there a file created if you replace `pyplot.show()` with `pyplot.savefig('test.pdf')`? Can you say us the output of `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.get_backend())`?

Comment: Well matplotlib shows up now, but now none of my data shows. I just had to append the IList and RList along with the SList

Comment: i feel there is something wrong with your algorithm. At no point are you calculating the number of infected, susceptible etc... you are just appending the list SList either to itself, or to IList or RList